# Can Augusta, Dean of Order's abilities be used twice if I have two in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have two [Augusta, Dean of Order](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Augusta%2C%20Dean%20of%20Order) and one [Oreskos Sun Guide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Oreskos%20Sun%20Guide) in play. One Augusta would allow Oreskos's Inspired ability

> Whenever Oreskos Sun Guide becomes untapped, you gain 2 life.

to trigger by attacking and untapping and I would gain two life. Would I be able to do this twice with two Augustas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would work. The specific sequence here would be (assuming neither you nor your opponent(s) interrupt at all):

- You attack, and this causes the triggered ability of each Augusta to trigger. As the controller of the abilities, you choose the order in which they are placed on the stack (although it really doesn't matter here)
- The top item on the stack (the trigger placed on the stack last) resolves, you untap all your creatures and then choose to tap Oreskos, gaining two life.
- The new top item (the trigger placed on the stack first) resolves, you again untap all your creatures and choose to tap Oreskos, again gaining two life.

[ This answer assumes you have found some way to make at least one of the Augustas non-legendary; plenty exist ]

Comment: Makes sense. I forgot about the legend rule, I'll have to investigate if it's worth adding the workaround. One last question since I'm just thinking about it; Augusta's text says "Whenever you attack..", does this mean when you begin the combat phase, declare attackers, or during combat? An example: I have an Augusta, another creature, say a generic green 3,3, and a [Felhide Spiritbinder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=378468). When I attack, I can use Augusta to trigger Felhide's Inspired ability and copy the 3,3. Is this new token able to partake in combat?

Comment: @Elrak02 the triggered ability of Augusta goes on the stack just after you attack, that is, in the Declare Attackers Step. Therefore the tokens created by the Felhide Spiritbinder cannot attack in that same turn, because you have attacked already. (Unless of course you find a way to get an additional combat steps, plenty ways to do that exist as well)